# Gitlab, get project/commit/file count from command line

Tags: gitlab

I want to display some basic stats about gitlab in my php script, but can't seem to find a way to get project/commit/file count from command line. Is it possible to get this information from command line? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use the API, possibly through clients like https://github.com/m4tthumphrey/php-gitlab-api or https://github.com/NARKOZ/gitlab

As for the precise data you want to get:

- project count: use the [project API](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/ef9f8677e65b4b791550daad4ebff8ae50c2f0d2/doc/api/projects.md) + [pagination headers](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/ef9f8677e65b4b791550daad4ebff8ae50c2f0d2/doc/api/README.md#pagination) - view detail how to get total page from response header key `x-total-pages` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49127473/248616)
- commit and commit count: currently not possible through the API. Requests that might make it possible: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3788030-the-api-should-support-showing-commit-details , http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6661459-api-allow-recursive-repository-tree. So you have to use `git` methods directly (not sure if possible without cloning).