# GitLab count total number of issues

Tags: api, count, gitlab

I would like to count all issues on my gitlab project using api.

Below the command that I'm using:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:xxxxxxx" https://gitlab.myapp.com/api/v4/groups/xx/issues?scope=all
```

I've also tried to replace groups with project.

We would like to bypass the pagination problem: the displayed results are always 100 (the max number).

How can we could get more than 100 ?

I would like to have as result only the total number of issue on my project.

Comment: have someone  the same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for anyone interestered I fixed it with this:

1. get the project ids of my gitlab

   curl -s -L --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:XXXXXX" "https://gitlab.XXXXX/api/v4/projects/"

combined with `python -m json.tool` and `sed` and `jq` and `grep` to get a list of ids and names.

then

I get the number of total pages of issues for project ids

```
curl -s --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:XXXXXX" "https://gitlab.XXXXX/api/v4/projects/${id}/issues?state=all&per_pages=100"
    | grep "X-Total-Pages"
```

then I extract all the issues with a `while` cycle:

```
 curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:XXXXX" "https://gitlab.XXXX/api/v4/projects/${id}/issues?scope=all&state=all&label_name\[\]=BU
    G&page=${i}&per_page=100"

$i is the page counter
```

I hope this could help someone else!

If you have questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Clever idea. Why wouldn't the developers simply include an endpoint in the API to get the total number of issues or even the information being set in headers in each request? How hard could that be?!!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61664510/fatch-projects-greater-than-100-from-gitlab-for-sourcegraph-projectquery

Comment: maybe no need to do the cycle.. there is a 'X-Total' field in ther response header :-)