# Fetch projects greater than 100 from gitlab for sourcegraph projectQuery

Tags: gitlab, sourcegraph

I am updating a sourcegraph's projectQuery configuration for gitlab but gitlab's (for the version I have) max count per page is 100 therefore, I can not get all the projects in a single query because I have more than 100 projects although I can add additional queries to fetch multiple projects but this I have to monitor and keep track of if the new projects are added that does not seems ntutive.

project query could look like this

```
"projectQuery": [
        "../v4/projects?per_page=100&page=1",
        "../v4/projects?per_page=100&page=2",
        ...
        ...
    ]
```

how can I improve this, a script could be better or extracts all the projects and add them to `projects`'s key in the config? I am asking here because this looks a very generic question

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829255/gitlab-count-total-number-of-issues

Comment: According to GitLab API documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#offset-based-pagination) there is no way to get more than 100 records per page; in other words, it's a hard max.

Comment: @AlekseyTsalolikhin, thanks. `--head`  can help us but again it would be multiple queries, so I was thinking to write a bash script to get all the projects and feed it to `projects` key.

Comment: Yep. It would be nice if there was a toolkit for the GitLab API, like octokib.rb for the GitHub API (see https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/#consuming-the-information)  -- I don't there is one yet, at least I couldn't find one!

Comment: Maybe you could use python-gitlab (https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html)?  `gitlab project list`

Comment: thank you for all the options :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

From reading the documentation, it seems that

```
gitlab project list --all
```

ought to return a list of all projects.

You can install it with:

```
pip install python-gitlab
```

Comment: Any ideas how I can do it in python directly?
(The link you've provided is not longer available)

Comment: Yep, looks like that project is gone now.  GitLab API is a standard REST API.

Comment: The project is not gone, only the link to it doesn't work anymore. https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
In any case, I was able to use it for my purpose. I recommend it.

Comment: Great!  Thanks @Lethargos! I've updated the URL.